# How to properly add error handling to image upload drag and drop form jquery

Tags: php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm creating drag and drop field to upload images. Everything works fine, files are uploaded successfully, but I lack knowledge how to properly add error messages for different outcomes like - it fails to upload for some reason, folder doesn't exists, upload success/fail messages. And also I would like to add some code that would clear out preview(gallery) section of the code when starting new batch/multiple image upload.
Could some one point me to right direction and help to understand better what should I do next to achieve intended result?

```html
<div id="drop-area">
  <form class="my-form" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" name="upload_image" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
    <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label>
  </form>
  <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
  <div id="gallery" ></div>
</div>
```

```
// ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)   
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}
let uploadProgress = []
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}

function uploadFile(file, i) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
  xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    }
    else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {

    }
  })


  formData.append('upload_image', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

upload.php

```php
$fileName = $_FILES['upload_image']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['upload_image']['type'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_image"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" .$fileName);
```

I have tried to put some echo's in upload.php for success message or fail, or just simple echo to at least output name of the file, but that brought no result at all. Not even single error message.

Comment: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seonn/7k9gmf68/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are actually halfway to the goal you are pursuing. In your `uploadFile(file, i)` function, you are testing the HTTP status code returned by your PHP script. You `updateProgress()` when you receive a 200 status code (Success) and everything went good.

If something wrong happens with the file upload, PHP will store the error message in `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']`.

You can just check at the end of your script whether this value is equal to  `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` (which means that the upload was successful) : in this case, your script should return a 200 status code (using [PHP's built-in `http_response_code()`](https://www.php.net/http-response-code)).

Else, set the status code to whatever you want (according to what the uploaded file's error message is, of course), and return this.

Your jQuery script will try to upload the file, receive an HTTP response with a set status code, and will accordingly continue with the execution, or show the error message you want to show based on the received status code (up to you to set the message).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. updateProgrress and status code 200 in this case affects only progress bar.
In normal php form error would be returned as `echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload_image"]["error"]`, but as I already mentioned, no echo is returned if put in to upload.php, even if code fails, php error isn't displayed. Removing upload.php in `xhr.open()`, or upload fail will still return 200 status code, will display progress bar and display preview of selected images.But still I can't understand how to catch that upload fail, display it as msg stop the preview and loading bar